# Trouble fetching JSONArray key from server

Tags: parse-platform

1) I have an Object (JB8XGctiZw) that has to keys: "patternName", and "tempoIntensities". When I run the following code, It will fetch the correct values of both keys.

```
ParseObject parseObject=ParseObject.createWithoutData("AudioPattern", "JB8XGctiZw");
parseObject=parseObject.fetch();
parseObject.pin();
Log.d("pattern",parseObject.getJSONArray("tempoIntensities").toString());
Log.d("pattern",parseObject.getString("patternName"));
```

2) From the web interface I change value contents for BOTH keys.

3) Run again the above code and it will successfully bring me the new value for "patterName", but "tempoIntensities", the JSONArray, will not be updated.

The only way to get the JSONArray updated is to clear local storage.

Is this a bug? Is this behavior normal?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with using ParseObject.getJSONArray and ParseObject.getJSONObject. For the moment I fixed this using ParseObject.get() and then casting it.
The version of Parse this applies to is 1.8.2,
And there is an assigned issue here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/846833412048862/

You should be logged in to facebook to see this bug